# Virtual host conf file not showing in apache2ctl -D DUMP_VHOSTS but works

Tags: apache-2.4, otrs

I want to test the OTRS ticket system so I installed it in an Ubuntu virtual machine to play with it. It's working perfectly, but I have a little doubt that I'd like to solve:

I have these 3 files in my 'sites-enabled' folder:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jul 10  2015 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 10  2015 scotchbox.local.conf -> ../sites-available/scotchbox.local.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Jan  9 15:10 zzz_otrs.conf -> /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf
```

Apache doesn't complain about any of them, so I suppose that they have the right syntax. The weird thing is that, when I want to display the virtual hosts, I get this output:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server scotchbox (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost scotchbox (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost scotchbox.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/scotchbox.local.conf:1)
                 alias www.scotchbox.local
```

As you can see, there's nothing about the file 'zzz_otrs.conf'. However, if I go to the url 'http://192.168.33.10/otrs/index.pl' I can enter into the OTRS administration panel and everything works just fine.

Is there an special flag to tell Apache not to show a configuration file?

It's an Apache 2.4.16 server on Ubuntu 14.04 (I also tried on an Apache 2.4.18/ Ubuntu 16.04 with the same result).

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the contents of zzz_otrs.conf. Does it have a `<VirtualHost>` directive in it?

Comment: Ok, that's the reason: the file doesn't have any `<VirtualHost>`. Instead, it has this directive: `<Location /otrs>`. I need to read more about the Apache configuration files... Thanks!

Comment: OK. Sounds as though that file belongs in `conf-enabled` instead of `sites-enabled` then.

Comment: I double checked the installation instructions and it says: `shell> ln -s /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zzz_otrs.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the configuration file has no `<VirtualHost>`directive, but a `<Location>` instead, so it's not showing when you run `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`.